# Read data from CSV file and format to use with requests

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to import data from a csv file and format it appropriately to allow me to submit it as a POST request to an api. Here is my code. I'd like to be able to pull the data from my csv and have it replace the 'rows' portion of the data, so I'm not typing in thousands of lines, but I can't seem to get the formatting correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',',header=0,parse_dates=True)
dfj = df.to_json(orient="records")

import requests
headers = {
     'Authorization': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
data = {
     'id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     'rows':[
         { 'field_0': 123, 'field_1': 'Sup', 'field_2': 16.5 },
         { 'field_0': 321, 'field_1': 'Nice', 'field_2': 16.2 },
         { 'field_0': xyz, 'field_1': 'Apple', 'field_2': 16.1 },
         { 'field_0': dfd, 'field_1': 'Orange', 'field_2': 19.2 }
     ]
}


response = requests.post('https://www.api.com/upload/data',
                         headers=headers,
                         json=data)
```

I'm sure I am overlooking something simple, but maybe I am going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I knew I'd figure it out sooner or later. Using the standard csv reader, I just needed to format as a dictionary list.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
     your_list = list(reader)
```

Now the data is in the proper format to be used for the API import.